# ng-table number range filter is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngtable

- what I am trying to do

I am trying to make one of my columns to take two number (in one column), so I can filter the numeric data by range just for this column. All other sort and pagination and filter by 'contain text' is working fine but I am just not sure how would I go about making just one particular column to have 'range' filter.

- graphical representation of what I want

  ```
  column_header1    columns_header2         column_header3

  contain_filter1   contain_filter2         filter3_min_number
                                            filter3_max_number

    data                 data                   numeric data
      .                    .                          .
      .                    .                          .
      .                    .                          .
  ```
- What I have so far

I found one example from ng-table module website and I tried to implement their code to mine but I don't know how to approach it when I have to implement the range function inside my 'getData'.
Example that I found http://codepen.io/christianacca/pen/yNWeOP
The custom filter algorithm on 'age' data was what I was looking at.

- my app.js

  ```
  $http.get("http://hostname:port/variant/whole/1-10000", {cache: true})
      .then(function (response) {

          $scope.variants = response.data;

          $scope.data = $scope.variants;
          var self = this;
          self.variantFilterDef = {
              start: {
                  id: 'number',
                  placeholder: 'Start'
              },
              end: {
                  id: 'number',
                  placeholder: 'End'
              }
          };
          self.variantsTable  = new NgTableParams({
              page:1,
              count: 10

          }, {

              filterOptions: { filterFn: variantRangeFilter },
              dataset: $scope.data,
              filterLayout: "horizontal"
          });

          function variantRangeFilter(data, filterValues/*, comparator*/){
              return data.filter(function(item){
                  var start = filterValues.start == null ? Number.MIN_VALUE : filterValues.start;
                  var end = filterValues.end == null ? Number.MAX_VALUE : filterValues.end;
                  return start <= item.pos && end >= item.pos;
              });
          }



          /* from this part on, it is working code but no 'Range'  function


          $scope.variantsTable = new NgTableParams({
              page: 1,
              count: 10

          }, {
              total: $scope.variants.length,
              getData: function (params) {
                  if (params.sorting()) {
                      $scope.data = $filter('orderBy')($scope.variants, params.orderBy());
                  } else {
                      $scope.data = $scope.variants;
                  }
                  if (params.filter()) {
                      $scope.data = $filter('filter')($scope.data, params.filter());
                  } else {
                      $scope.data = $scope.data;
                  }
                  $scope.data = $scope.data.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count());
                  return $scope.data;

          }


      });






   */



    });



  });
  ```

  - my variant.html

    ```
      <table ng-table="variantsTable" show-filter="true" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed">
          <tr ng-repeat="variant in $data">


       <td data-title="'chrom'" sortable="'chrom'" filter="{ 'chrom': 'text' }" >
    {{variant.chrom}}
       </td>

      <td data-title="'id'" sortable="'id'" filter="{ 'id': 'text' }" >
    {{variant.id}}
      </td>


      <td data-title="'pos'" sortable = "'pos'" filter = "{ 'pos': 'text' }">
    {{variant.pos}}
      </td>
    ```

I would really appreciate any suggestion or any input, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filter attribute of the ID table cell is not correct.

```
<td data-title="'id'" sortable="'id'" filter="{ 'id': 'text' }">
    {{variant.id}}
</td>
```

Change it to:

```
<td data-title="'id'" sortable="'id'" filter="variantFilterDef">
    {{variant.id}}
</td>
```

**EDIT**

After a bit of trial and error I have it working.  I started from your code sample and made a number of changes. I used ControllerAs syntax. But essentially the fixes are:

1. `<td data-title="'chrom'" sortable="'chrom'" filter="{ 'chrom': 'text' }">`

   to `<td data-title="'chrom'" sortable="'chrom'" filter="{ 'name': 'text' }">`
2. `<td data-title="'pos'" sortable = "'pos'" filter = "{ 'pos': 'text' }">`

   to `<td data-title="'pos'" sortable="'pos'" filter="variantCtrl.variantFilterDef">`
3. `if (params.filter()) {
           self.data = $filter('filter')(self.data, {name: params.filter().name});
           self.data = variantRangeFilter(self.data, params.filter());
       } else {
           self.data = self.data;
       }`

The main issue was the need to separate out the filters of the two columns in #3 by using `{name: params.filter().name})` & then calling the custom Pos filter separately.

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QKBYOq?editors=1011

Comment: Codepen example uses `<td data-title="'Age'" filter="demo.ageFilterDef">`

Comment: I know I just posted the answers that I've been working with. I've tried that and code pen example uses demo(controller name).ageFilterDef and I tried mycontroller.variantFilterDef and it did not work.

Comment: I need a way to implement that function inside my getData function because all the filter functions are happening inside there.

Comment: I have more js code commented out if you scroll down below.

Comment: If you can post a more complete code sample with the controller & html I can help diagnose and test my answer

Comment: I bought codepen account and tried to simplify my code by removing routing  and putting in sample data set but its not working atm, I'll try more once I get off from work. Thanks for your help and I really appreciate it.   http://codepen.io/gopokes1986/pen/LRBdVG?editors=1010

Comment: I was getting the data from http get before so now I put some sample data set for range function testing.

Comment: No problem. I'll look at it in a few hours and get back to you

Comment: http://codepen.io/gopokes1986/pen/xEaKVy?editors=1010#0 , I got it to here now all I have to do is to make the two filters for one column showing up. it is not showing up for some reason tho